# Singular Matrix error while fitting Logistic Model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression

I am building a Logistic Model for Binomial classification for network Intrusion Detection System

After splitting the data:

```
formula1='label_Normal ~ '+ ' + '.join(Features_after_vif)


train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split( data_train[Features_after_vif],
                                              data_train['label_Normal'],
                                              test_size = 0.3,
                                              random_state = 123 )
```

and building the model on train dataset,

```
logreg1 = sm.logit(formula1,train_X)
```

I am getting below error:

```
----> 1 logreg1 = sm.logit(formula1,train_X)
  2 result = logreg1.fit()
  3 summ = result.summary2()
  4 summ


C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
 packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py:1788: RuntimeWarning: divide 
by zero encountered in log
return np.sum(np.log(self.cdf(q*np.dot(X,params))))
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
     Current function value: inf
     Iterations: 35
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-f3465b6dcb3c> in <module>
  1 logreg = sm.logit(formula1, data=train_X)
----> 2 result = logreg.fit()
  3 summ = result.summary2()
  4 summ

 ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, 
method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
1899         bnryfit = super(Logit, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
1900                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
 -> 1901                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
1902 
1903         discretefit = LogitResults(self, bnryfit)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, 
method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
214         mlefit = super(DiscreteModel, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
215                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
--> 216                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
217 
218         return mlefit # up to subclasses to wrap results

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in 
fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, fargs, callback, 
retall, skip_hessian, **kwargs)
475             Hinv = cov_params_func(self, xopt, retvals)
476         elif method == 'newton' and full_output:
--> 477             Hinv = np.linalg.inv(-retvals['Hessian']) / nobs
478         elif not skip_hessian:
479             H = -1 * self.hessian(xopt)

<__array_function__ internals> in inv(*args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in inv(a)
545     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
546     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 547     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
548     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
549 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in 
_raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
 95 
 96 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 97     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
 98 
 99 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Not sure why it is giving me "Singular Matrix" error. Please help to resolve it.

If necessary, I can share the jupyter notebook and dataset as well.

Answer (score 0):

While fitting the model, it should be fit only on train data :

In `logreg1 = sm.logit(formula1,train_X)`
instead of `formula1`, use `train_y`

If that doesn't resolve it, data must be checked to be clean.

Comment: I guess this api syntax accepts dataframe instead of array,please try this : 

`data_train_model=data_train[Features_after_vif]`

`logit = sm.logit(formula = formula1, data = data_train)`